# How to declare a storage variable in vyper?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, vyper

I am trying to convert my solidity code into vyper but I can't find a way to declare a storage variable.

My solidity function was this:

```
struct Account {
uint256 balance; // Account's balance
uint256 timeLocked; // If not 0, then account will be allowed to withdraw 
}
mapping (address => Account) public accounts;

function addBalance() public payable {
Account storage a = accounts[msg.sender];
a.balance = a.balance + msg.value;

}
```

How can I make `a`to become a storage variable ?

I have another question, how can I make a require statement like this ?

```
require(_operator != address(0));
```

Seems that address(0) doesn't exist in vyper as it throws me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just bypass the use of `a` completely?

```
struct Account:
    accountBalance: wei_value
    timeLocked: uint256

accounts: public(map(address, Account))

@public
@payable
def addBalance():
    self.accounts[msg.sender].accountBalance += msg.value
```

Note that `balance` is a reserved keyword, so I've used `accountBalance`.

---

> Seems that address(0) doesn't exist in vyper as it throws me errors.

Use:

```
assert _operator != ZERO_ADDRESS
```

`ZERO_ADDRESS` is a [built-in constant](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.10/types.html?highlight=zero_address#built-in-constants).

Comment: Actually I use `a` to emit an event  `emit Balance(msg.sender, a.balance);`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, there isn't a lot of documentation out there

Comment: Just poking around at Vyper examples, it doesn't look like storage or memory _pointers_ are implemented, so I think you might have to use `self.accounts[msg.sender]` explicitly in your event call: `log.Balance(msg.sender, self.accounts[msg.sender].accountBalance)`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! 


Do you know how to declare a getter function, I've tried like this `def getBalance() -> uint256(wei):` but it creates a setter function instead

Comment: Glad it worked :-) Getter functions can be created implicitly (as they are in Solidity) by using the `public()` function. So when we declared the mapping, you'll notice it was wrapped in a `public()` call. This means the getter function should be automagically created, and so you don't need to explicitly create one.

Comment: Okay, search for "getter" on this doc page: https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.10/vyper-by-example.html#simple-open-auction

Comment: Thank you again, I was used to solidity docs which have much more content. Last question and I will stop  bothering you. I was used in writing this in solidity:  `uint256 public withdrawInterval = 7 days;` but as I can see there isn't the keyword for days in vyper. How can I even do that ?

Comment: No problem :-) I think you have to use a `timedelta` variable, and specify the number of seconds (which is all the `minutes`, `hours`, `days` keywords do in Solidity under the covers). Have a look at https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.10/types.html?highlight=time#time

Comment: This auction contract has some examples of how a time limit can be set: https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.10/vyper-by-example.html#simple-open-auction